# Android repo sync doesn't create src directories

Tags: android, android-source, repo

I'm trying to compile AOSP for 6.0.1 from source. There's a strange issue I'm seeing for which I haven't found similar posts.

After downloading the source using `repo sync -f`, repo finishes, but the source directory is empty. It just contains the `.repo` directory. (`.repo` is > 30G, so the downloading was fine)

While doing `repo sync -f` there were a few packages which failed to be fetched. Others have reported sync issues but don't seem to have issues seeing the source or compiling it after repo sync has finished.

Here's what I've tried so far with not much success:

1. Initially repo init was initialized with android-6.0.1_r41. Then tried `repo init` with master branch.
2. Changed the tcp window to 0 as mentioned here: https://source.android.com/source/known-issues.html#difficulties-syncing-the-source-tree-tcp-issues
3. Update git to latest version.

This is running on virtualbox Ubuntu 16.04.

Is there anyway to force an 'unpack' of the source?

Comment: Sync should run without `-f`, especially if you have an empty directory. What errors do you get?

Comment: have you tried checking out the branch?

Comment: One of the errors is like this : " Fetching projects:  54% (276/511)  error: Cannot fetch platform/external/sl4a
warn: --force-broken, continuing to sync " . There are a few more of these. No I haven't tried checking out. Will try.

Answer (score 0):

If you repo sync finished but got no src code.
just try

```
repo sync -c --no-tags --local-only -j4
```